# SqlBulkCopy C# Excel all data with sheet names

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want insert Excel sheet data to SQL Server. This Excel data sheet has many work sheet, I want insert all data with excel sheet name. I wrote code it insert two step in my SQL Server table.

Can you please tell me how to insert data with particular sheet name.

E.g.

```
Name Address WorksheetName
N1   A1     Sheet1
N2   A2     Sheet1
N3   A3         Sheet2
```

Code:

```
OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

oledbconn.Open();

DataTable dt = oledbconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

if (dt == null)
{
   Response.Write("No record Found");
   //return;
}

DataRow row = dt.Rows[1];

// Get Excel sheet Name
//String[] SheetName = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
foreach (var sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(excelConnectionString))
{
    for (int c = 0; c < sheetName.Length; c++)
    {
        string SheetName = row[c].ToString();
        string myExcelDataQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "]";

        OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myExcelDataQuery, oledbconn);
        OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();

        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TlcmealsContext"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(conn);

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTemps";

            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt.CreateDataReader());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the SqlDataReader. The SqlBulkCopy
                // object is automatically closed at the end
                // of the using block.
                dr.Close();
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: It's coming following error
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147217900
  Message=Syntax error in FROM clause.
  Source=Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
  ErrorCode=-2147217900
  StackTrace:
       
SheetName value _xlnm#Print_Titles
myExcelDataQuery value  SELECT * FROM [] 
+$exception {"Syntax error in FROM clause."} System.Exception {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException}

Comment: sheetName value "'Bob-Ann169$'" and  SheetName value null

Comment: I think issue comes that line string SheetName = row[c].ToString(); how do I change this line?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use built-in SQL option to import data from EXCEL? [image]

This has worked for me to import data from EXCEL/Access.

Comment: I am using web base application. C#, MVC 5